# prevent radio button to be checked when clicked unless it is unprotected

Tags: excel, vba

I want to prevent Excel active-x radio buttons located in protected cells to be clicked unless the cells protection is lifted.
How to do this?
the code I am using is this one:

```
Private Sub OptionButton17_Click()
    If OptionButton17.Value = True Then OptionButton18.Value = False
    AuthorisationFlag = True
    AuthorisationLevel AuthorisationFlag
End Sub
```

I don't want `OptionButton17` or `OptionButton18` to be clicked unless previous conditions are set.
If I lock the Linked Cell this has no effect either if I lock the cell on which the buttons are placed.
Any suggestion?

Comment: When you protect the cells, why not include something like `OptionButton17.Enabled = False` and when un-protecting simply do the opposite?

Comment: Thank you.  I checked it and it worked well.

Comment: But now I tried applyin the same method for Checkbox and this didn't work.

Comment: If the Checkbox is an ActiveX control and not a Form Control, then the same should work, but if you used the Form Control then you can disable it by making it invisible? Like so `ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 1").Visible = False`